# Can't get code to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make my own adaption of a simple jQuery shooting game I found online. The problem is IU cannot get it to work and have no idea why. I understand this question is vague but I cannot make it any more to the point as I don't know the point of the problem. Can someone please help me get it working...

http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/SKB3Q/2/

Comment: poor question subject. not much effort or description except "look at my fiddle".

Comment: You to *at least* say what its supposed to do.

Comment: You need to make more of an effort to debug the issue yourself. Then raise a question regarding the issue.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'`

Comment: if you know your question is vague, why not putting a little bit effort into details / code source etc. ?

Comment: It's working after I've added `jquery` and `ui` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SKB3Q/5/) from the left pane `Choose framework`.

Answer (score 3):

In your jsfiddle you are using Mootools not jQuery in the dropdown boxes to the left, this is atleast part of your problem.

**Update:** After Selecting the `jquery` and `ui` from the left pane of jsFiddle (Chose Framework) [it's working here](http://jsfiddle.net/SKB3Q/5/).

Answer (score 1):

In your jsfiddle you have selected Mootools 1.4.5 as the JS library - if you change this to jQuery 1.8.2 it seems to be working.